# Session and HttpContext not available in web part

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, session

I have a web part in which I have Grid View which displays data from a custom list. In the `Page_Load` I am initializing the `DataTable`. I want to store the `DataTable` object in `Session` object so that it wont fetch it again and again, similar to what has been done in this [example](https://gist.github.com/kerenapura/6994620).

```
Session["data"] = dataTableObject;
```

But the code shows compile time error.

> The name 'Session' does not exist in current context.

I even tried to to use `HttpContext` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969595/1047998).

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["data"] = dataTableObject;
```

But it shows the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your webpart you need to change the web.config:

```
<pages enableSessionState="false" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*******" asyncTimeout="7">
```

to

```
<pages enableSessionState="true" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*******" asyncTimeout="7">
```

and also add this in:

```
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
```

the above goes within:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

so you need to find the modules tag and add it in, it will look somthing like this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

then within your webpart you can do:

to save string:

```
Page.Session["storethis"] = "hello world";
```

to get string:

```
string helloWorld = Page.Session["storethis"].ToString();
```

also how is your class made? are you inheriting from the webpart class? im asking becasue this error is shown when you dont inheirt from a class (webpart or page) or not set within web.config

as an example this is my redirect class webpart that redirects when on a page that is loaded, it gets the session value that im soring (url) and redirecting:

```
public class httpRedirectHome : WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        changeRedirection(Page.Session["PreviousPageUrl"].ToString());


        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private void changeRedirection(string url)//,string extentionType)
    {
        if (Page.Session["PreviousPageUrl"] != null)
        {
            Page.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see its a webpart that iv made (public) and im inheriting from `webpart` class

```
public class httpRedirectHome : WebPart
```

if it was an aspx.cs it would be somthing like:

```
public partial class showBifDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You'd need to enable Session State in your web application.

1. Execute the following powershell script `Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision`
2. Apply the following `web.config` change:

   ```
   pages enableSessionState="true"
   ```

More information is available at: [Using Session State in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: notice that #1 is actually `SharePoint 2010 Management Shell window`. normal `PowerShell` window will throw `Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision`

Answer (score 1):

For me I just needed to run this PowerShell Command and it works

```
Enable-SPSessionStateService -DefaultProvision
```

After this, the following works

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["toto"] = "toto";
```